# how activities (that can have different pid) can have access to a subcalss of Application?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I know that passing objects between activities must be using `serialisation` or `Parcelable` and we connot pass objects directly between activities.

When I did more research about why not directly use objects, I found that activities can have different pid ( witch make sense since we cant access memory of other process).

But what i dont understand is: 
why all activities can access the sub class of Application in project ?(with `getApplicationContext()` )

I hope my question is clear, any help is apreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: if they have different pid, they access a different instance of the application.

Comment: so if they are more than one instance, if I have for example an object in one instance it can't be access by other activity that have other intance? so the Application is not a singleton-like? or there is some magic that keep both instances syncronised? I'm sorry this answer lead me to more questions :D

Comment: I am curious as to what lead to have 2 activities from the same application running in different processes in the first place, though

Comment: I have a little experience on android and I never did it :) and it's just curiousity , I just try to know more my Job :D anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: 2 processes are like 2 different application. They don't share memory, therefore I don't see how the application singleton could be shared. If you are using 2 activities in different processes, consider them as being in different applications.

Comment: I see what you mean now :) in the manifest we can have 1 or more <application> tag for a"group" of activities inside so thats where we specify the class and instrances are created depending of the number of tag <application>, now its clear. 
but usually we use just one instance so all activities are in the same process, if I'm right, I dont know why they dont let the possibility to pass object if it's the same pid memory to pass object without serialise them

Comment: I don't think you can put several `<application>` in one manifest. The process is indicated by the `android:process` attribute (optional) for each Activity.

Comment: The reason for not passing object in Intents is that the intent does not know to which process it is going when you create it. This is resolved much later.